# I want to use TFS 2008 (using MSF for Agile 4.2) for Test Case and Defect management, pls. tell how

Tags: tfs

We are using TFS 2008 for source code. The process template chosen was Agile 4.2. 
I have installed VSTS 2010 to access TFS 2008 server.
Can someone please guide me on how to enable TFS 2008 with the ability to add Workitems - Test Case and Scenario into it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Microsoft Test Manager (also known as Visual Studio Test Professional 2010) with Team Foundation Server 2008. It requires implementation on the server which is not available in TFS 2008.

See [Software Requirements for Visual Studio Application Lifecycle Management Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg265786.aspx#bkmk_vstestpro) on MSDN:

> To use Visual Studio Test Professional 2010, you must also install
>   Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2010.

You can however create a Test Case and Scenario work item type in TFS 2008. This would just be a plain old work item form, no different to a Task or Bug like you already have.